# IRanges - minoverlap

Tags: r

I'm trying to use IRanges to group a set of ranges into unique sets. I want there to be at least an overlap of 100. This is not working. Can anyone help me out? I suspect it is has something to do with how `reduce()` is working but I can't seem to figure out the solution.

Example:

```
start.vec<-c(2021,2378,2718,2275)
end.vec<-c(2374,2737,3408,3408)
ir<-IRanges(start.vec,end.vec)
grouped<-subjectHits(findOverlaps(ir,reduce(ir),minoverlap=100))
```

Comment: Where is IRanges from? Edit: Oh, I see, it's a Bioconductor package.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are looking for, but if I

```
> hits = findOverlaps(ir, minoverlap=100L)
```

I get an object that tells me which queries overlap which subjects, where query and subject are in effect the same ranges

```
> hits
Hits of length 10
queryLength: 4
subjectLength: 4
   queryHits subjectHits 
    <integer>   <integer> 
 1          1           1 
 2          1           4 
 3          2           2 
 4          2           4 
 5          3           3 
 6          3           4 
 7          4           1 
 8          4           2 
 9          4           3 
 10         4           4
```

I could get a list of sets as

```
> split(subjectHits(hits), queryHits(hits))
$`1`
[1] 1 4

$`2`
[1] 2 4

$`3`
[1] 3 4

$`4`
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

you could exclude self hits with

```
> hits1 = hits[queryHits(hits) != subjectHits(hits)]
```

The [Bioconductor mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/) is a good resource for asking these questions